Mean Absolute Error from Scratch in NumPy
I recently tried implementing MAE from scratch in NumPy. The loss value and the slope seem to be equivalent to what Scikit-learn outputs, but for some reason the intercept value seems to converge to the wrong value!
Curious to know what might be wrong in my implementation?
def mae(y, pred):
    l = np.mean(np.abs((y - pred)))
    return l

def mae_grad(y, pred):
    return - np.sign(y - pred)

def backwards(x, y, pred):
    dz = mae_grad(y, pred)
    dw = np.dot(dz, x.T) / 352
    db = np.sum(dz) / 352
    return dw, db

#OUTPUT: 

#slope: [[3.95191571]]
#intercept: [[39.98615341]]
#mse: 19.441714929551242


The rest of the code is at this repo if needed

This is the sklearn version
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x_reshaped, y_reshaped)
y_pred = reg.predict(x_reshaped)

loss = skm.mean_absolute_error(y_reshaped, y_pred)

#OUTPUT
#Scikit-learn slope: [[3.83597589]]
#Scikit-learn intercept: 47.683903862891924
#Mean square Error: 19.598373700357737


what does the / 352 do?

352 is my sample size. averages the gradients.

typically, you would use np.mean or at least something like len(x) instead of the hardcoded size

gotcha, thanks for the heads up

Sklearn is minimizing the mean squared error (MSE). You just print the MAE of a model, that was trained to minimize the MSE.
Your code on the other hand seems to minimize the MAE.
Having different loss functions is probably the reason for the differences.
For a more detailed explanation, why the intercept differs stronger than the slope, one would have to look into the data.
Note: Although you write #mse: 19.441714929551242, your code actually outputs the MAE:
def mae(y, pred):
    l = np.mean(np.abs((y - pred)))
    return l

# ...
l = mae(y, pred)

# ...
print(f"mse: {l}")


I assume it's the same for sklearn

yes my bad, printing the ouput as 'mse' was a typo. it's actually both mae.

Nevertheless, sklearn optimizes the mse. I would assume this is the main reason for the difference.

huh?
I used loss = skm.mean_absolute_error(y_reshaped, y_pred)

I am not sure where/how you use the loss, but the fitting (as shown above) does not use it:
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x_reshaped, y_reshaped).

By the way: LinearRegression from sklearn does not support optimizing for different loss function (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

I confirm the answer of @Bloele and want to add, that in order to perform a MAE optimization with scikit-learn you should use another regressor:
sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor(loss='epsilon_insensitive', epsilon=0)

